# How can I make Python re work like grep for repeating groups?

Tags: python, regex, grep

I have the following string:

```
seq = 'MNRYLNRQRLYNMYRNKYRGVMEPMSRMTMDFQGRYMDSQGRMVDPRYYDHYGRMHDYDRYYGRSMFNQGHSMDSQRYGGWMDNPERYMDMSGYQMDMQGRWMDAQGRYNNPFSQMWHSRQGH'
```

also saved in a file called `seq.dat`. If I use the following `grep` command

```
grep '\([MF]D.\{4,6\}\)\{3,10\}' seq.dat
```

I get the following matching string:

```
MDNPERYMDMSGYQMDMQGRWMDAQGRYN
```

which is what I want. In words, what I want to match is as many consecutive repeats as the string has of `[MF]D.{4,6}`. I don't want to match cases where it has less than 3 consecutive repeats, but I want it to be able to capture up to 6.

Now, I'm trying to do this with python. I have

```
p = re.compile("(?:[MF]D.{4,6}){3,10}")
```

Trying `search()` returns

```
MDNPERYMDMSGYQMDMQGRWM
```

It is the close to the answer I seek, but is still missing the last `MDAQGRYN`. I'm guessing this is because `.{4,6}` matches the `M`, which in turn prevents `{3,10}` from capturing this 4th occurence of `([MF]D.{4,6})`, but since I asked for at least 3, it's happy and it stops.

How do I make Python regex behave like grep does?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate so if I understand correctly, you want a `M` or `F`, followed by a `D`, followed by between 4 and 6 of _any character_ (`.`), and you want this to repeat between 3 and 10 times? If `M` is one of the characters matched by a `.`, you want this to indicate the start of a new group of `[MF]D....`? In that case, you probably don't want to match `.`, like Wikor suggested in the answer below.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that is a very good point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between POSIX ("text-directed") and NFA ("regex-directed") engines. POSIX engines (`grep` here uses a POSIX BRE regex flavor, it is the flavor used by default) will parse the input text applying the regex to it and return the longest match possible. NFA engine (Python `re` engine is an NFA engine) here does not re-consume (backtrack) when the subsequent pattern parts match.

See [*reference on regex-directed and text-directed engines*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html):

> A regex-directed engine walks through the regex, attempting to match the next token in the regex to the next character. If a match is found, the engine advances through the regex and the subject string. If a token fails to match, the engine backtracks to a previous position in the regex and the subject string where it can try a different path through the regex... Modern regex flavors using regex-directed engines have lots of features such as atomic grouping and possessive quantifiers that allow you to control this backtracking.
>
> A text-directed engine walks through the subject string, attempting all permutations of the regex before advancing to the next character in the string. A text-directed engine never backtracks. Thus, there isn’t much to discuss about the matching process of a text-directed engine. In most cases, a text-directed engine finds the same matches as a regex-directed engine.

The last sentence says "in most cases", but not all cases, and yours is a good illustration that discrepances may occur.

To avoid consuming `M` or `F` that are immediately followed with `D`, I'd suggest using

```
(?:[MF]D(?:(?![MF]D).){4,6}){3,10}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rewexi/1). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of an outer non-capturing container group:

  - `[MF]D` - `M` or `F` and then `D`
  - `(?:(?![MF]D).){4,6}` - any char (other than a line break) repeated four to six times, that does not start an `MD` or `FD` char sequence
- `){3,10}` - end of the outer group, repeat 3 to 10 times.

By the way, if you only want to match uppercase ASCII letters, replace the `.` with `[A-Z]`.